# Font-face shifting out of place in Google Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, font-face, webfonts

I know there are browser rendering inconsistencies between Chrome and Firefox (Windows, both). But I am seeing a weird bug involving @font-face & gooogle-fonts shifting the font down about 10px in Chrome.

Here is an image to illustrate the problem. I have highlighted the text so that you can see the shift:

[image: Screenshots from Chrome and Firefox]

Here is the CSS for clarity:

```
.primary-menu li a,
.primary-menu li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right: 0;
    transition: padding-right .5s;
}
```

I am using Google Fonts for the Oswald type face:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Oswald:400,700' type='text/css'>
```

I am using a CSS reset, so most properties are set to a default value. I have tried fiddling with the CSS to see if I can analyse why it is shifting, but I can not see an effect other than turning off the font-face.

Here is the source site for reference. [Concept Design Ltd](http://www.conceptdesignltd.co.uk)

Any knowledge on why this is happening would be fantastic.

Many thanks,
Neil

Comment: Strange. I have the same version of Chrome and I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: Same here, no problems in Chrome...

Comment: Thanks @PeterVR I am not sure what the problem is then! I will look at my extensions etc to see why mine is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, but in FireFox - I removed the Oswald fonts I had in my font directory on my computer and it fixed the issue. Maybe give that a go?

Comment: Thanks @Jez. Yes I had the fonts installed locally on my PC. Disabled them and suddenly the shift disappears. Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem, but my font was NOT locally installed. (By the way, that would be a problem in web design, as you cant control the installed fonts on pageviewer´s computer).
The problem only occurred in Chrome 26 on Windows, and later in Firefox 19 for Windows but not on any other browser (neither Windows nor Mac OS x).
I finally found out that Chrome/Win would only render SVG Font correctly and Firefox took WOFF unhinted.

So I dirty-fixed the uncorrectly-rendered down-shifting with this-like CSS-code

```
/* for all browsers */
@font-face {
font-family: 'myfont';
src: url('myfont.eot');
src: url('myfont?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('myfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('myfont.svg#wf') format('svg');
}

/* for all webkit-browsers (Chrome, Safari and newly Opera */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('myfont.svg#wf') format('svg');
  }
}

/* for all mozilla-browsers (Firefox) */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  @font-face {
font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('myfont_unhinted.woff') format('woff');
  }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Thanks @Florian for posting your solution. I am sure it will help a lot of ppl out. +1 for pointing out the fact the problem will affect ppl viewing your site.